# .NET SyncFramework sync scope

Tags: .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I have to synchronize two databases, local and remote. 
If I have this example:

Local DB:
**1. John
2. Joe
3. Mark**

Remote:
**1. John
2. Joe**

and I synchronize the two databases the end result will be be that I will have all three records in both databases, but the synchronization process will have triggered errors for records #1 and #2 (cant insert them) since they exist in both. By default the Sync framework wont do anything in this case and will just continue, which is OK for me.

Is there a way to set the synchronization scope so that only non-identical records from both databases to be synchronized (and as a result these errors will not be not generated in the first place)?

My code looks like this (from Microsoft's sample code):

```
SqlSyncScopeProvisioning serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(remoteServerConn);
DbSyncScopeDescription remoteScopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(remoteProvisioningScopeName);
DbSyncTableDescription tableDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(remoteTableName, remoteServerConn);
remoteScopeDesc.Tables.Add(tableDesc); 
serverProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(remoteScopeDesc);                   serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);    
serverProvision.Apply(); 
SqlSyncScopeProvisioning clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(localServerConn);
DbSyncScopeDescription localScopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(remoteProvisioningScopeName, remoteServerConn);
clientProvision.PopulateFromScopeDescription(localScopeDesc);
clientProvision.Apply();
SyncOrchestrator syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(remoteProvisioningScopeName, localServerConn);
syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider(remoteProvisioningScopeName, remoteServerConn);    
syncOrchestrator.Direction = syncDirection;
((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += new EventHandler<DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs>(Program_ApplyChangeFailed);
SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework does an incremental sync i.e., what has changed since the last sync, not what's different between source and destination